# Powershell: read Json file with string having space in between

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read json file from powershell and one the value field string has space in between. When I am trying to read json I am getting an error

Error

```
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: .
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

content of JSON file

```
{
   "TestStringKey":"Test String Value"
}
```

Powershell script to read json file

```
$jsonString = Get-Content $jsonFileLocation   | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I tried to use backtick but that did not work.

Comment: Double-check what `Get-Content $jsonFileLocation` gives on its own. The JSON you quote is valid and converts just fine. You can test this by copying the text, then doing `Get-Clipboard | ConvertFrom-Json`. If necessary, check the file with an editor like Notepad++ for invisible characters or other encoding issues.

Comment: There is a dot (`.`) somewhere outside of quotes in the json you are using as opposed to what you are showing, like the real json is `{"TestStringKey":"Test String Value"}.`